# How to map path parameter which is not at path end using Mapping Template when using AWS API Gateway with AWS Lambda?

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Assuming a route like this is defined in the API Gateway:

`POST /projects/{projectid}/key`

which is mapped to an AWS Lambda,

how could one get that `{projectid}` value in the Lambda handler (i.e. as a field of the input object which is a custom Java class)?

As far as i understood, something like this should do the job:
In the API Gateway definition, Integration Request > Mapping template i've added the following for the content-type "application/json":

```
{ "projectid": "$input.params('projectid')" }
```

However, even if the part after the colon (`$input.params('projectid)` seems to be picked-up correctly (in the API Gateway logs from CloudWatch the value looks as expected), the mapping is not working: `null` value reaches the backend.

Please note that a similar approach for a route like

`GET /projects/{id}` works as expected with similar mapping.

Looks like the path param only gets mapped if it is the last one in the path?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo on your part but the mapping template rule should be ``{"projectid": "$input.params('project-id')"}``.  That should pull the value associated with ``project-id`` regardless of where it is in the path.

Comment: sorry, that is a typo indeed, but only in the question, not in code/config - it's projectid everywhere

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what the problem is then.  I have often used variables with the resource path and then pulled them out using templates.  It doesn't seem to matter where they show up in the path.  Sometimes I even have multiple variables within a single path. I've always been able to access them via the ``$input.params()`` mechanism.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will keep this thread updated as soon as i find the issue (i hope to receive an answer from Amazon support soon).

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem.
It was not the Mapping Template itself,
but the way i was invoking the AWS SDK function.
Specifically:

```
apigClient.projectsProjectidKeyPost(params, {}, {})
```

does not work - projectid arives `null` in the Lambda code.

However, this works (please note the change in the 2nd argument value):

```
apigClient.projectsProjectidKeyPost(params, '{}', {})
```

Not sure what exactly is the root cause of this behavior though.

Comment: Hmm this is an interesting observation. I'll add something to our backlog to investigate this behavior. 

Edit: It may be that the mapping template you had configured wasn't applied to the request in the first case. The mapping template is chosen based on the Content-Type header, so it's possible that in the first case the client wasn't sending the Content-Type header since no content was being sent.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your Java Lambda handler to make sure the deserialization is handled correctly. You could start with a simple NodeJS function for testing that would not require a RequestHandler implementation (it will deserialize everything in the JSON payload without any handler configuration).
2. Not sure if you're talking about the same API here, but you should not be allowed to have two path parameters on the same segment, i.e. /projects/{id} and /projects/{projectid} should not coexist in the same API.
3. You could start with using $input.params() to get all your parameters and confirm that 'projectid' is coming through in that map. Again, this would be easier to debug in a NodeJS function.